# Error when verifying a clear signed SMIME message

Tags: openssl, pkcs#7, smime

I've a message like this in file testSmimeMsg.txt:

```
ABC is our biggest acquisition ever and as you can imagine, customers
and partners alike are eager to hear how we plan to integrate it into
XYZ.  Specifically, how are we going to bring the two traditionally
separate silos of desktop and mobile together?
To help explain our vision for uniting we released a
video describing our architecture and
technology integration plans.  Definitely watch the video to learn more,
and the rest of this blog will give you a summary of our plans and a bit
more color on certain areas.
```

I use following command to make a clear signed message:

```
$ openssl smime -sign -in testSmimeMsg.txt -out testSmimeClearTextMessage.txt -signer sender.pem
```

The sender.pem is generated from a .p12 file and it has CERTIFICATE and RSA PRIVATE KEY contents.
Then I use the following command to verify the signed message I just created.

```
$ openssl smime -verify -in testSmimeClearTextMessage.txt -noverify -out testSmimeVerifiedClearTextMessage.txt
```

The result is Verification Successful and content in testSmimeVerifiedClearTextMessage.txt is same as testSmimeMsg.txt. Perfect!
Now Lets say I want to verify the same by the PKCS7_verify() method.
C code

```
jbyteArray aw_SMIME_Verify_Signature_And_Get_Message(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jbyteArray signedMsg, jstring senderCertPath, jstring rootCertPath)
{
    //SenderCertPath and rootCertPath are currently NULL. For now, I just want openssl
    //to extract the signer cert from message and verify message. Root certificate and chain
    //of trust verification etc is ignored for now.

    jbyteArray cmsContent = NULL;


    PKCS7 *pkcs7 = NULL;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    ERR_load_X509_strings();
    ERR_load_PKCS7_strings();
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();

    pkcs7 = getP7FromEncryptedMessage_SMIME(env, signedMsg); //this works. pkcs7 is non null.

    if (pkcs7 == NULL) {
        LOGE ("aw_SMIME_Verify_Signature_And_Get_Message: Error reading p7 from message. Returning");
        goto exit_free;
    }
    cmsContent = verify_Signature_And_Get_Message(env, pkcs7, senderCertPath, rootCertPath);

    exit_free:
    if (pkcs7) {
        PKCS7_free(pkcs7);
        pkcs7 = NULL;
    }

    return cmsContent;
}

------------------------------
PKCS7 *getP7FromEncryptedMessage_SMIME(JNIEnv *env, jbyteArray encryptedSMIMEMessage) {

    BIO *in = NULL;
    int encryptedMessageLength = 0;
    const unsigned char *encryptedBuf = NULL;
    PKCS7 *p7 = NULL;

    //obtain the p7 structure from the encrypted message
    encryptedMessageLength = env->GetArrayLength(encryptedSMIMEMessage);                    //get size of encrypted message byte[]
    encryptedBuf = (const unsigned char *)env->GetByteArrayElements(encryptedSMIMEMessage, 0);                                              //create a buffer of that size
    in = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    BIO_set_mem_eof_return(in, 0);
    BIO_write(in, encryptedBuf, encryptedMessageLength);                                    //create a BIO with the char* of encrypted message

    p7 = SMIME_read_PKCS7(in, NULL);                                            //get the p7 structure

    if(in) {
        BIO_free(in);
    }
    if (encryptedBuf) {
        env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(encryptedSMIMEMessage, (jbyte *)encryptedBuf, 0);
    }

    return p7;

}
----------------------
jbyteArray verify_Signature_And_Get_Message(JNIEnv *env, PKCS7 *pkcs7, jstring senderCertPath, jstring rootCertPath)
{
    X509* rootCert = NULL;
    X509* senderCert = NULL;
    STACK_OF(X509) *st1 = NULL;
    X509_STORE* m_store = NULL;
    BIO *out = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    BIO_set_fp(out, stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);
    BUF_MEM *bptr = NULL;
    jbyteArray cmsContent = NULL;
    int cmsLen = 0;

    if(rootCertPath != NULL) {
        rootCert = getCertificateFromPath(env, rootCertPath);
        m_store = X509_STORE_new();
        //TODO: check what to be in cert store
        X509_STORE_add_cert(m_store,rootCert);
    }

    if(senderCertPath != NULL) {
        senderCert = getCertificateFromPath(env, senderCertPath);
        st1 = sk_X509_new_null();
        sk_X509_push(st1, senderCert);
    }
    //st1 and m_store are NULL as they are not used for now.
    int verifyResult = PKCS7_verify( pkcs7, st1, m_store, NULL, out, PKCS7_NOVERIFY);
    if(verifyResult != 1) {   //FAILS HERE!!!!
        LOGE ("verify_Signature_And_Get_Message: Error verifying signer certificate. Returning");
        LOGE(ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        goto exit_free;
    }
    BIO_get_mem_ptr(out, &bptr);

    cmsLen = bptr->length;
    cmsContent = env->NewByteArray(cmsLen);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(cmsContent, 0, cmsLen, (jbyte *)bptr->data);

    exit_free:
    if (serverCert) {
        X509_free(serverCert);
        serverCert = NULL;
    }
    if (rootCert) {
        X509_free(rootCert);
        rootCert = NULL;
    }
    if (m_store) {
        X509_STORE_free(m_store);
        m_store = NULL;
    }
    if (st1) {
        sk_X509_pop_free(st1, X509_free);
    }
    if (out) {
        BIO_free_all(out);
        out = NULL;
    }

    return cmsContent;
}
```

When run, I get error:

```
 verify_Signature_And_Get_Message: Error verifying signer certificate. Returning
 error:2107507A:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_verify:no content
```

Can someone please tell me whats wrong?
Please note that if I pass a signed-data message, with the code unchanged, it works. I get the verification successful and plaintext data back but when I'm sending a clear signed data, it fails.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. The problem was that I wasn't using the content parameter of PKCS7_read_SMIME() API. If the message is clear signed, the message content is returned in this parameter which is then needed to be passed to PKCS7_verify() method along with NODETACHED flag. See opeenssl doc for both APIs for more details.